# can we configure mod_qos so, error logs related to mod_qos will be in a different file other than apache default error logs

Tags: php, apache, ddos

I have implemented anti-DOS modules (mod_qos) on my dedicated apache2 server. my site has a heavy traffic and my error log filled in seconds with the following error

---

mod_qos(034): access denied, QS_SrvMinDataRate rule (in): min=120, this connection=0, c=xxxxxx
mod_qos(031): access denied, QS_SrvMaxConnPerIP rule: max=50, concurrent connections=51, c=xxxxxx

---

which will make it hard to get actual php errors, is there a way to set that mod_qos will log these errors to another file other than apache default error log file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a hack to this as following:
i have create a subdomain and treat it as default domain for the server, change the main domain error-logs file name in vhost. after this all the mod_qos error goes to default error-log file and main domain error goes to newly created errorlogs file.

i am sharing the solution so someone with same situation will get the clue.